# What is this button in gnome shell for? It does nothing

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-gnome, button

I have a strange button in gnome that doesn't seem to do anything, and whenever I see screenshots of gnome shell online no one else seems to have it.

Can anyone tell me where it comes from, what it is for, and how I can get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a screen rotation lock but this is just a guess because I haven't used Gnome in years.

Comment: Being connected to *mordor*, I'll be worried... (`me /ducks`) :-)